# missingDimensionStrategy everywhere - Is there no better way?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have a library project - let's call it `lib1` which has custom `flavorDimensions` specified. More precisely there is `buld` dimension with actual flavors `full` and `production`.

This library is used by another library project (`lib2`) with no custom `flavorDimensions` specified and `app` project with dependency to `lib2` but not directly to `lib1`.

To tell `lib2` which flavor of `lib1` to use I can specify `missingDimensionStrategy 'build', 'full'`. Great. Mission accomplished, right?

Well not really... Project won't sync because `app` project doesn't know which flavor of `lib1` should it use??? I need to put the `missingDimensionStrategy 'build', 'full'` to the app project as well. You can imagine that if you try to build a well modularized app. This line will be practically in every build.gradle which transitively depends on `lib1`.

Is this how it should be? Can't I tell gradle somewhere globally what flavor to use? I wanted to add the dependency with `debugApi project (path:':xxx', configuration: 'fullDebug')` etc. but that doesn't work... :(

Can anybody give an advice? Thanks.

Comment: I think this a bug with the Android Gradle plugin. Just filed it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131710432

Comment: Both your issue in Google [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131710432) tracker and child [issue](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9330&sa=D&source=buganizer&usg=AOvVaw0R4ULNLAJD_J836dTx3ORZ) in Gradle Github repo is closed as not planned